# Revert to previous commit Windows Azure

Tags: git, azure

We have Windows Azure to synchronize our code from Visual Studio. We are building an ASP.NET MVC 4 website. A member of the team, made a few mistakes at the last commit, and we want to delete that commit, or revert a previous commit. I searched a lot, but I cannot find how to do that using Windows Azure. Can you help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: Q: Are you using GIT?  Or SVN?  If so, are they hosted on Azure?  Other than that, what exactly does Azure have to do with anything?

Comment: @FoggyDay - Azure Web Sites integrates with TFS, git, dropbox and numerous others for deployments.

Comment: @Jim - please edit your question to clarify what you're deploying to: Web Sites? Cloud Services (via deployment package)?

Comment: @FoggyDay Thanks a lot for your comment. I am using the Visual Studio Git addon. (never used the actual program of git). I can view my source from Windows azure, like github. And I am asking if it is possible to revert at a previous commit from there, or at least use an other easy way to do that

Comment: I am deploying an MVC Website @DavidMakogon.

Comment: please fix your tags, they are misleading

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Hi. Why they are misleading? ;) I am using all of the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should revert the last commit (using [git revert](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html)) and then commit and push to get your site redeployed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Git integration deployment to Website, you can revert your previous deployment from the azure portal. Just go to the website deployment page, all your deployment should be listed and you can select one of them and click deploy button at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. You just got my +1